# Python -- class vs module

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, module, python-module

I'm working on a group of functions that are probably easier to manage on their own, just in a module.  But there are reasons beyond my pay-grade that would like to think about turning this into a class.  But, since it's converting from a polynomial input as a string, the regex works on a string but once the input is a class instance then it just decides to quit after that.

So my question is how to turn this into a class and still maintain the functionality (how to initialize it, etc).  Or if this case is better suited to being a module then I can argue that but I need to understand fully.  I checked these out but I'm not really sure I'm getting enough out of them to solve this issue:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

[organising classes and modules in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498200/organising-classes-and-modules-in-python)

```
import re

def id(lst): #returns modulus 2 (1,0,0,1,1,....) for input lists
    return [int(lst[i])%2 for i in range(len(lst))]

def listToInt(lst):  #converts list to integer for later use
    result = id(lst)
    return int(''.join(map(str,result)))

def parsePolyToListInput(poly):
    c = [int(i.group(0)) for i in re.finditer(r'\d+', poly)] #re.finditer returns an iterator
    return [1 if x in c else 0  for x in xrange(max(c), -1, -1)]

def prepBinary(x,y):  #converts to base 2 and orders min and max for use
    x = parsePolyToListInput(x); y = parsePolyToListInput(y)
    a = listToInt(x); b = listToInt(y)
    bina = int(str(a),2); binb = int(str(b),2)
    #a = min(bina,binb); b = max(bina,binb);
    return bina,binb  #bina,binb are binary values like 110100101100.....

def add(a,b): # a,b are GF(2) polynomials like x**7 + x**3 + x**0 ....
    bina,binb = prepBinary(a,b)
    return outFormat(bina^binb)  #returns binary string

def subtract(x,y):  # same as addition in GF(2)
    return add(x,y)

def multiply(a,b):  # a,b are GF(2) polynomials like x**7 + x**3 + x**0 ....
    a,b = prepBinary(a,b)
    return outFormat(a*b)  #returns product of 2 polynomials in gf2

def divide(a,b): #a,b are GF(2) polynomials like x**7 + x**3 + x**0 ....
    a,b = prepBinary(a,b)
    #bitsa = "{0:b}".format(a); bitsb = "{0:b}".format(b)
    return outFormat(a/b),outFormat(a%b)  #returns remainder and quotient formatted as polynomials

def quotient(a,b): #separate quotient function for clarity when calling
    return divide(a,b)[1]

def remainder(a,b): #separate remainder function for clarity when calling
    return divide(a,b)[0]

def outFormat(raw): # process resulting values into polynomial format
    raw = "{0:b}".format(raw); raw = str(raw[::-1]); g = [] #reverse binary string for enumeration
    g = [i for i,c in enumerate(raw) if c == '1']
    processed = "x**"+" + x**".join(map(str, g[::-1]))
    if len(g) == 0: return 0 #return 0 if list empty
    return processed  #returns result in gf(2) polynomial form

def extendedEuclideanGF2(a,b): # extended euclidean. a,b are values 10110011... in integer form
    inita,initb=a,b;  x,prevx=0,1;  y,prevy = 1,0
    while b != 0:
        q = int("{0:b}".format(a//b),2)
        a,b = b,int("{0:b}".format(a%b),2);
        x,prevx = (int("{0:b}".format(prevx-q*x)), int("{0:b}".format(x,2)));  y,prevy=(prevy-q*y, y)
    #print("%d * %d + %d * %d = %d" % (inita,prevx,initb,prevy,a))
    return a,prevx,prevy  # returns gcd of (a,b), and factors s and t

def modular_inverse(a,mod): # a,mod are GF(2) polynomials like x**7 + x**3 + x**0 ....
    a,mod = prepBinary(a,mod)
    bitsa = int("{0:b}".format(a),2); bitsb = int("{0:b}".format(mod),2)
    #return bitsa,bitsb,type(bitsa),type(bitsb),a,mod,type(a),type(mod)
    gcd,s,t = extendedEuclideanGF2(a,mod); s = int("{0:b}".format(s))
    initmi = s%mod; mi = int("{0:b}".format(initmi))
    print ("%d * %d mod %d = 1"%(a,initmi,mod))
    if gcd !=1: return outFormat(mi),False
    return outFormat(mi)   # returns modular inverse of a,mod


a = "x**14 + x**1 + x**0"; b = "x**6 + x**2 + x**1"
c = "x**2 + x**1 + x**0"; d = "x**3 + x**1 + x**0"
e = "x**3 + x**2 + x**1 + x**0"; f = "x**2"; g = "x**1 + x**0"
p = "x**13 + x**1 + x**0"; q = "x**12 + x**1"
print "add: [%s] + [%s]  =  %s "%(a,b,add(a,b))
print "add: [%s] + [%s]  =  %s "%(c,d,add(c,d))
print "multiply: [%s] * [%s]  =  %s "%(a,b,multiply(a,b))
print "multiply: [%s] * [%s]  =  %s "%(c,d,multiply(c,d))
print "multiply: [%s] * [%s]  =  %s "%(f,g,multiply(f,g))
print "quotient (max(a,b)/min(a,b): [%s] / [%s]  =  %s "%(a,b,quotient(a,b))
print "quotient (max(a,b)/min(a,b): [%s] / [%s]  =  %s "%(c,d,quotient(c,d))
print "remainder (max(a,b) mod min(a,b)): [%s] mod [%s]  =  %s "%(a,b,remainder(a,b))
print "remainder (max(a,b) mod min(a,b): [%s] mod [%s]  =  %s "%(c,d,remainder(c,d))
valuemi1 = modular_inverse(a,b)
print "modular_inverse: [%s] * [%s] mod [%s] = 1  [%s]"%(a,valuemi1[0],b,valuemi1[1])
valuemi2 = modular_inverse(p,q)
print "modular_inverse: [%s] * [%s] mod [%s] = 1  [%s]"%(p,valuemi2[0],q,valuemi2[1])
```

Each of the arithmetic operations just takes in a GF(2) polynomial in string format then parses it into the respective binary values, then sends it the outFormat() for converting back into a polynomial.  Works fine now, so I'm leaning toward not fixing it if it isn't broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just a novice python developer, but if I understood your question correctly then you need to code something like this:

```
import re
class MathOperations:
      def id(_self, lst): #returns modulus 2 (1,0,0,1,1,....) for input lists
            return [int(lst[i])%2 for i in range(len(lst))]
```

and then you can use the class:

```
obj = MathOperations()
obj.id([1, 2])
```

Comment: thanks just what i was looking for. just 2 things: 1. most of the classes i see use `class Math(object):` instead of `class Math:` ... 2. then when you create an instance and use it, i'm not sure why it was running into regex issues but now this instance seems to process input ok...

Comment: @Rami: it may be better to use the standard ``self`` variable -- improves readability.

@stackuser: it seems that all you are trying to do is to package a few functions into a class. I don't see your function exchanging data. so why not use static functions. example:

``    class MathOperations:
        @staticmethod
        def id(lst):
            return [int(val)%2 for i, val in enumerate(lst)]
``
couple of things to notice:
you can call like:
    MathOperations.id([1,2])

Comment: sorry for the messed up formatting but didn't want to add a new comment

Comment: @Rami: not sure what you mean by not 'exchanging data' -- seems like only 4 or 5 out of 13 don't call each other. all the rest use some other function there. so like, outFormat(), id(), etc don't call 1 of the others.